# Using Limit Multiplication Law Produces Different Answers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (0 \cdot \sin(n)) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (0 \cdot \sin(n)) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(0) \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\sin(n)) = 0$(DNE)

Which answer is the correct one?

Comment: The product rule that you are using is valid only when both limits exist, I.e. $\lim(a_n b_n)=(\lim a_n)(\lim b_n)$ is valid when both limits exist on the right.

Comment: The same problem appers by calculating $\lim_n 1$ and $(\lim_n \frac{1}{n})(\lim_n n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $$\lim_n (a_nb_n)=\lim_n a_n \lim b_n$$ if the three limits exist. In your case you can't apply it because $\lim_n \sin n$ does not exist. But, if $a_n=0$ then

$$\lim_n (a_nb_n)=\lim_n 0=0.$$ Or, more generally:

If $\lim_na_n=0$ and $b_n$ is bounded then $\lim_n (a_nb_n)=0.$

Comment: The theorem states that if the factor limits exist, then the limit of the products exists too. Thus you only need to assume the existence of 2 of the 3 limits. (And if you include the condition for quotients, it does not matter which 2).

Comment: Why does b_n need to be bounded?